# AWS EMR Impala daemon issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr, impala

I've just created EMR cluster and trying to create my first Impala table. Getting this error: This Impala daemon is not ready to accept user requests. Status: Waiting for catalog update from the StateStore. Any suggestion please? I did everything as documented by Amazon.

```
[ip-10-72-69-85.ec2.internal:21000] > connect localhost;
Connected to localhost:21000
Server version: impalad version 1.2.1 RELEASE (build d0bf3eae1df0f437bb4d0e44649293756ccdc76c)
[localhost:21000] > show tables;
Query: show tables
ERROR: AnalysisException: This Impala daemon is not ready to accept user requests. Status: Waiting for catalog update from the StateStore.
[localhost:21000] >
```

Comment: Any update about this issue?

Comment: I just recreated cluster and it's gone. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error - after many troubles I've found the simple solution:

A. Check `impala-state-store` and `impala-catalog` daemons are running:

```
sudo service impala-state-store status
sudo service impala-catalog status
```

If not running - check the logs and be sure to activate them.

B.If they are running - simply type in your `impala-shell`:

```
invalidate metadata;‏
```

This command will update your catalog from the state store.

Then, you are ready to start!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in the said order and reopen the Impala browser

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hive-metastore start
sudo /etc/init.d/impala-state-store start
```

And

```
sudo /etc/init.d/impala-catalog start
sudo /etc/init.d/impala-server start
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution to this problem might be to just wait. I had this problem and had restarted everything impala with no luck. I even tried stopping all impala services and starting them in the recommended order (statestore first). Nothing helped but then after an amount of time of being left it started to work. I'm not sure what that time is but it was more than 5 minutes and less than an hour.

Answer (score -1):

I would first recommend you check the logs at /mnt/var/log/apps. The error is likely related to the state-store, which can be restarted with the command below.

```
sudo service impala-state-store restart
```

Comment: I didn't defined any state store. I see mysql instance running but it is empty. Should I do any additional step to define "meta store" after cluster creation?

Comment: You don't need to manually add anything, it's pre-configured. Did you launch your machine with Hadoop 2.x and Impala support?

Comment: Yes, I did. Will check your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I did. It isn't supported for 1.x Hadoop version.  Will check your suggestion. I see that when I choose to create cluster with Impala the Hive didn't work properly as well: I unable to select specific column from external hive table and able to perform only

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same error.  The tutorial skipped a couple steps.  Once in an impala-shell, create a database, then use the database, then create a table.

Comment: hmmmmm, impala shell doesn't work when you are getting these errors.